# Unable to add a credit/debit card for billing account on Firebase

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-billing

Sorry if this is not the correct place to put up this question, but I'm unable to find an answer anywhere else.
Here's the problem.
I need to upgrade a client's account on Firebase from Spark plan to Blaze plan (pay as you go plan).
To do that I need to add a credit/debit card as a payment method to their account (billing account).
We have tried 3-4 different credit/debit cards but have failed.
I tried getting help from the help center but was not able to find it there.

At this link - https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat  - I tried to chat with someone to get help but here's what I got -

[image: google chat help]

I am not the administrator on any billing account - **Because I am unable to add a credit/debit card to create a billing account, hence I am not eligible for any help**

I cannot get help on Phone because **"You do not currently have access to technical phone support"**

I am really frustrated by this, I have tried multiple cards, even borrowing other people's credit cards.

I am unable to find help from Google! Community support is the last option left! I just want to know what the issue is with my credit card? Why am I not able to add it as a payment method?

It was not registered for international payments initially, but I got that changed. I do not have any other ideas.

I really hope you guys can help me out.

UPDATE 1:

> You must create a billing account first before you can add a card/payment options. Information about it can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account

I followed this link, this is something I've tried and this is the step where I am stuck.
Step 1: Identity verification - I am able to successfully complete this step by verifying mobile number and continuing.
Step 2: Verify payment method - this is the step I am stuck at. I have tried adding different cards, as mentioned above, and have faced different issues with different cards. One card did not have international payments enabled, I got that enabled but even then it doesn't work. It does not show any error. It proceeds to the bank's website for two step verification process, I enter the 'One Time Password" for the payment, the payment goes through and it comes back to the same "Payment Information Verification" page.
Screenshots attached below for more info

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: *firebaser here* Sorry to hear about the the frustrating experience you've had, but this is not a great place to help with billing issues. I recommend [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/billing/upgrade) for personalized help in troubleshooting

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The page you linked says "You must be added as a billing administrator in the org permissions. Contact the org administrator for help." I am unable to create a billing account because I am unable to add a credit card for billing which is my primary issue. I have added more detail to my original question, maybe that helps. Thank You!

Comment: Darn, I hoped that link would work and put you in the right queue immediately. This is the more general deep link: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/products/other
I have no idea what's going wrong, but am definitely not an expert on the (quite complex) Cloud billing infrastructure.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This support link helped somewhat, although the issue is still not resolved. India just got a new bunch of rules and so credit card cant be added. More details at https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/payment-methods#supported_payment_methods

Comment: I.might have a similar issue. I cannot pay for.my google account, tried paying with three different cards. My banks state that gcp dont even try to charge, gcp state that banks refuse the transactions.

Comment: @Vojtěch turned out to be an issue on the bank's end. Checking with the bank might help.

Answer (score 0):

You must create a billing account first before you can add a card/payment options.
Information about it can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account

Instructions for creating a payment profile is here: https://support.google.com/paymentscenter/answer/9028746?ref_topic=9017383

It is important to set yourself up as the appropriate individual or business type.
Once that is done, you can link it to your account and your client's project if you have the permissions to do so.

**Update**

**Google Support**

It is advised to create a new Google Cloud Account through this link provided https://cloud.google.com/

**Additional**

Failing this, you can use the troubleshooter to find the appropriate contact support [HERE](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/9664343#ts=9664644%2C9664940%2C9664455%2C9664557)

Inputting your issues has lead to a possible suspension on your account which suggests filing a ticket, available here: https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_suspensions

Comment: Added update 1 to the answer, please share any further advice you have. Thank You!

Comment: Interesting seems something maybe stuck or glitched. I would contact Google Billing, it's beyond Firebase's reach - internally they would just escalate it anyway.

Comment: I have been trying to get in touch with Google Billing but I am unable to do that as I have already mentioned in the question. I tried to get help using chat or phone but have failed to do so as I am not a paying customer, but I cannot become a paying customer because ??? - I am stuck in a loop!

Comment: I'll contact them on your behalf, I have two billing accounts so I have access through that dumb bot.

Comment: Using some debuging I found a form for support tickets
I'll update my answer

Comment: Thank You! I would be grateful for your help. I will meanwhile try to contact them using the form you shared. I already filled a form that FrankvanPuffelen shared, but am still awaiting a reply on that.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**!!

**Problem** -> Since recurring payments are blocked, we cannot add cards and create billing account. And since I didn't have any billing account, I was not allowed the chat support. When I mailed regarding the same, received reply after 2-3 days stating that we look for some other payment methods(which do not exist as of now if you are in INDIA).

**Solution** -> Connect with some friend outside India where recurring payments are enabled(for eg. USA, singapore).
Ask them to login firebase from their laptop(do not use their card in India), add billing account and then google will put account on hold for 24-48hrs. go to cards -> add a backup card (India card) -> make it primary card and **BOOOOM!!**. In probably 24 hrs you can make payments from Indian credit/Debit card. Thank me Later!!